# How to paint the component at maximum size to an image with Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

I've been looking for a way to paint the JSwing component to an image for which I found many answers.
What I haven't found is the way to paint the component in such a way for it to ignore current window size and print itself to an image at full preferred size.

I have components in a re-sizable frame. After making it smaller some components are cropped.
What I want is to paint this frame into an image at its preferred size regardless.

```
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(getPreferredSize().width,
            getPreferredSize().height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
    this.printAll(g);
```

This results in an image as seen on the resized window, but I want it to paint itself like it has enough preferred space regardless of window or computer screen size.

Edited.

Here is SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(100, 100);
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Long text. Long text. Long text. Long text.");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(lbl);
        JButton btn = new JButton("Screenshot");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(getPreferredSize().width,
                        getPreferredSize().height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
                printAll(g);
                try {
                    ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", new File("image.jpg"));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        });

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(btn, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

This creates a small window with a button and a label which is too long to be displayed fully. Button takes the screenshot as is. What I want is an image.jpg which has fully visible texts on button and label, as if the frame was large enough for them to fit.

If I do this:

```
Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
lbl.printAll(g); // instead of printAll(g);
```

I get the label fully printed to image.jpg (ignoring the frame boundaries). I want to do that with all the components of a frame.

Comment: Try changing `BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(getPreferredSize().width,
            getPreferredSize().height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);` to `pack(); BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(getPreferredSize().width,
            getPreferredSize().height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);`.  If that does not do the trick, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: That does work but it is not what I want. Pack() changes the window size which is not desirable. I tried storing current dimensions and resetting them after pack but that produces obvious flicker for the user.

Imagine the frame is a 'window' above an 'image'. 'Image' is larger than the frame so the user only can see part of it. What I want to do is allow user to store the contents of the frame to BufferedImage. This bufferedimage when outputted to a file will produce the complete 'image' not just what is visible through the 'window'

Comment: *"Imagine the frame is.."* Imagine posting an SSCCE.

Comment: Put the image inside a JScrollPane.

Comment: JScrollPane results with the same thing as JPanel. I don't need to see the whole label in the window of the application, I just want to see it whole in the outputted image file.

Comment: Just call setSize(...desired size...) before printAll()